# How to count downwards with forEach loop javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

So I want to go through an list of objects but I cant index it but can use forEach to go through the elements... My problem is I need to go from the last Object to the first but dont know how to do that with the forEach function! If i'd do a for loop it would look something like this:

```
var test = [1,2,3,4,5]
   for (let i = test.length; i > -1; i=i-1) {
       console.log(test[i])
   }
```

But as I explained I somehow cant index it. So can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `reverse()` the array before the loop:

```js
var test = [1,2,3,4,5]
 
test.reverse().forEach(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for your problem:

```js
var test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    for (let i = test.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      console.log(test[i])
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of Severin.Hersche's approach:

```js
const test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for (let i = test.length;i--;) console.log(test[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

```js
var test = [1,2,3,4,5]
test.forEach((val, index) => console.log(test[test.length - index - 1]));
```